# Calendar for hotel's booking system

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm trying to create a booking system for a hotel. The system will be used by the hotel's administrator, not by the customers.
On the rows i need to see the rooms (100,101,ecc..) and on the columns i need the days.
I'm using the TimelineView, with the initial view set to "resourceTimelineWeek".
I can add the rooms and get it to work, but i don't need to see the hours of days, just the days. The room is reserved at least for one full day.
This is my basic code, i've tried with the option "allDaySlot" without luck.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
                    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                        initialView: 'resourceTimelineWeek',
                        allDaySlot : true,
                        resources: [{
                                id: '1',
                                title: 'Room 101'
                            },
                            {
                                id: '2',
                                title: 'Room 102'
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                    calendar.render();
                });
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotDuration

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry for the delay! I've tried without luck

Comment: What exactly did you try? And what exactly was the result? We can't help much if you aren't specific

Comment: You're right, sorry for uncomplete reply. I've used a different plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `slotDuration: { day: 1 }`.

```js
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  initialView: 'resourceTimelineWeek',
  allDaySlot: true,
  slotDuration: {day: 1},
  resources: [{
      id: '1',
      title: 'Room 101'
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      title: 'Room 102'
    }
  ]
});
calendar.render();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.5.1/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.5.1/main.js"></script>


<div id="calendar"></div>
```